# Python get data from named pipe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, fifo

How do I read from a named pipe in Python 3.5.3?

The pipe's name and location is `/tmp/shairport-sync-metadata` and it can be viewed by anybody, but only modified by the `shairport-sync` user.
Other websites and questions say to use `os.mkfifo("pipe-location")` but I've been getting this error:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.mkfifo("/tmp/shairport-sync-metadata")

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    os.mkfifo("/tmp/shairport-sync-metadata")
FileExistsError: [Errno 17] File exists
```

Is there a way to get around this? Sorry for the nooby question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`os.mkfifo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo) is used to **create** fifo. Use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) to open/read fifo already exist:

```
with open('/tmp/shairport-sync-metadata') as f:   # add `rb` for binary mode
    # line-by-line read
    for line in f:
        print(line)

    # f.read(1024)  # to read 1024 characters
```

Comment: Thanks! How stupid of me :P One thing I noticed was when I started a song, the metadata was split into 3 lines per item. This is just probably a shairport-sync thing, but it'll mean I'll have to join the strings together when I parse them. +1 and accepted.

Comment: Hope this helps.
https://github.com/luckydonald/shairport-decoder
https://github.com/idubnori/shairport-sync-trackinfo-reader